# Game loop and time measurement

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

There is the function `Sys_Milliseconds`:

```
int curtime;
int Sys_Milliseconds (void)
{
    static int      base;
    static qboolean initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
        base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;
        initialized = true;
    }
    curtime = timeGetTime() - base;

    return curtime;
}
```

Used in time calculation in the Quake 2 main game loop implementation:

```
//...
oldtime = Sys_Milliseconds();
//...
while (1) {
        //...

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
            if (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit();
            sys_msg_time = msg.time;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        do {
            newtime = Sys_Milliseconds();               
            time = newtime - oldtime;
        } while (time < 1);
//...
}
```

I'm wondering about the usage of the `Sys_Milliseconds` at all. What's the point in `base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000` line? Why are they applying the 0xffff0000 mask on the retrieved time? Why not just use the `timeGetTime` function directly:

```
//...
oldtime = timeGetTime();
//...
while (1) {
        //...

        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE)) {
            if (!GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
                Com_Quit();
            sys_msg_time = msg.time;
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        do {
            newtime = timeGetTime();                
            time = newtime - oldtime;
        } while (time < 1);
//...
}
```

Comment: Fun fact: A `static` local variable is initialized exactly once and this (as of C++11) is guaranteed even if threading is involved. `static int      base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;` is all you need to guarantee correct initialization of `base`

Comment: Is there a reason for tagging this C++? The code is written as C, isn't it?

Comment: Best guess: the first 16 bits just don't matter.

Comment: @user4581301 But that isn't possible in C. (Which is probably relevant since I still think the question is just mistagged.)

Comment: _"Why not just use the `timeGetTime` function directly"_  One function reports the time since Windows started.  The other reports the time since Quake 2 started.

Comment: @user17732522 Almost certainly considering the example apparently came from the Quake 2 code. Makes this a bit of a cautionary tale.

Comment: A 49.7 day-long game of Quake would be... epic. And probably real-world fatal.

Comment: @DrewDormann "One function reports the time since Windows started. The other reports the time since Quake 2 started" Which function reports the time since Quake 2 started? Can You please explain it?

Comment: @darro911 the function that returns `timeGetTime() - base;`, where `base` is approximately the the `timeGetTime()` when Quake 2 started.  Subtracting a time from another time gives you the duration between those times.

Comment: @Frank "Dropping 16 bits of milliseconds is kind of bonkers because it means that the returned value will be negative for a random time up to 32 seconds after the first call." - sorry friend but I don't get it - can You please give me an example?

Comment: @DrewDormann How could the `base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000` gives the time since when Quake 2 was started!?

Comment: @darro911 as mentioned in the very first comment, `base` is a `static` variable.  It's initialized only once, the first time the function is called.  Stack Overflow does not work well as a discussion forum, so if you have more questions, you may need to click that "Ask Question" button.